# Docker for Desktop Kubernetes Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:6445

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I am using Docker for Desktop on Windows 10 Professional with Hyper-V, also I am not using minikube. I have installed Kubernetes cluster via Docker for Desktop, as shown below:

[image]

It shows the Kubernetes is successfully installed and running.

When I run the following command:

```
kubectl config view
```

I get the following output:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
  insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
  server: https://localhost:6445
  name: docker-for-desktop-cluster
contexts:
 - context:
   cluster: docker-for-desktop-cluster
   user: docker-for-desktop
   name: docker-for-desktop
   current-context: docker-for-desktop
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: docker-for-desktop
user:
  client-certificate-data: REDACTED
  client-key-data: REDACTED
```

However when I run the

```
kubectl cluster-info
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:6445: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

It seems like there is some network issue, I am not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I know this is an old question but the following helped me to resolve a similar issue. The root cause was that I had minikube installed previously and that was being used as my default context.
I was getting following error:

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.1.8:8443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

In the power-shell run the following command:

```
> kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME                 CLUSTER          AUTHINFO         NAMESPACE
      docker-desktop       docker-desktop   docker-desktop
      docker-for-desktop   docker-desktop   docker-desktop
*     minikube             minikube         minikube
```

this will list all the contexts and see if there are multiple. If you had installed minikube in the past, that will show a * mark as currently selected default context. You can change that to point to **docker-desktop** context like follows:

```
> kubectl config use-context docker-desktop
```

Run the get-contexts command again to verify the * mark.

Now, the following command should work:

```
> kubectl get pods
```

Comment: Wow this was hard to find :)

Answer (score 0):

Posting a response to this very old question, as I was searching for a solution and later found a different cause for my problem and the solution was simple.

1. Cause was that the config file was missing from the $HOME$/.kube directory
2. A simple restart of Docker Desktop restored the file with some defaults and things were back ok.

Side note: The issue started after I upgraded my Docker Desktop Installation to latest (when I got the update available popup). I should also mention that the cluster stopped working and I had to manually remove Docker Desktop and Reinstall the latest version (this was the story before the problem occurred).